# What it means that ActivePython "includes openssl"?

Tags: python, openssl

ActivePython webpage has a list of [included things](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/whatsincluded.html) that includes something called "OpenSSL version 0.9.8r". What this means for Windows? Is it some Python module like "M2Crypto" that will be available, or is it just a new name for standard "ssl" python module that is very limited and is included in standard Python distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's referring to [pyOpenSSL](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL).

Comment: I have installed ActivePython on Windows, but `import pyopenssl` fails. Why?

Comment: @EyeOfHell: because the module is called [`OpenSSL`](http://packages.python.org/pyOpenSSL/).